# Prevent onclick from cascading down

Tags: javascript, dom-events, jstl

I have a custom tag that produces a clickable image that calls a servlet that does some "stuff".  Here is an example of what the tag produces:

```
<c:set var="epMethodToCallAttribute" value="methodToCall.performLookup. ..."/>
${kfunc:registerEditableProperty(KualiForm, epMethodToCallAttribute)} 
<input type="image" tabindex="${tabindex}" name="${epMethodToCallAttribute}" src="${lookupicon}" border="0" class="tinybutton" valign="middle" alt="Search ${fieldLabel}" title="Search ${fieldLabel}" />
```

unfortunately I can't really change the tag library, so I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
<div id="searchIconDiv" onClick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?')){}"> 
  <c:set var="epMethodToCallAttribute" value="methodToCall.performLookup. ..."/>
  ${kfunc:registerEditableProperty(KualiForm, epMethodToCallAttribute)} 
  <input type="image" tabindex="${tabindex}" name="${epMethodToCallAttribute}" src="${lookupicon}" border="0" class="tinybutton" valign="middle" alt="Search ${fieldLabel}" title="Search ${fieldLabel}" />
</div>
```

But for this to work, I need to do something to the effect of capturing the click event and preventing it from cascading down to the image that tag produces.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what was needed for the div tag I proposed:

```
<div id="onClickDiv" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
```

Got this from another Stackoverflow question.